# remotely run Genymotion

Tags: remote-desktop, tightvncserver

I want to run Genymotion remotely on my host(Ubuntu 16.04).

I have installed `Tightvnc` server on the host and connect to it using `Tightvnc` viewer.

I get the following error:

```
invalid mit-magic-cookie-1 keyAborted (core dumped) (1)
```

I have try following:

```
export DISPLAY=MYWINIP:0 (2)
```

- MyWINIP is the IP address of my windows which is connected to Ubuntu host using VNC

But I still get error:

> Aborted (core dumped)

**Edit Question:**

I try putty as Yaron suggetion, but the application open and closed before it completely loaded. Here is the application log: `The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?`

I want to run some Genymotion devices on remote host. I have only remote access to the host. When I try to run Genymotion remotely I get (1) error and i find (2) solution for it but it doesn't solve the problem. any suggestion is appreciated.

PS : host is not connected to any monitor is this make problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Genymotion need monitor connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the below command, is that your X server Display will be your  windows IP:

```
export DISPLAY=MYWINIP:0
```

If you didn't install X-Server on your windows machine

- X application won't be able to open / directed to Windows machine without X server support

Note that, if you have both:

- X-Server running on your windows machine
- ssh client on your windows machine (note that Windows 10 Bash support `ssh` command)

Using `ssh -Y` (X11 forwarding option) might be the best solution for running application on your Unix machine, and redirecting the display-output to your Windows screen.

[Here - how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) - You can find details how to set windows `putty` to use X11 forwarding

> **man ssh**
>   -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

[xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is an example for X-server application which runs on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I install xming, how can I use X11 forwarding option?

Comment: @user3933607 - try using `ssh -Y` from windows 10 - bash

Comment: mine is windows 7, It didn't recognize -Y option

Comment: @user3933607 - updated my answer with link to `putty` with instruction for `x11 forwarding`

Comment: It doesn't solve  the problem. I update question with more detail

Answer (score 0):

you just need x11vnc instead of vncserver because x11vnc support GPL2.0

officail explain:

Why can't I start Genymotion remotely?
To use Genymotion remotely, you must have a remote access tool that supports OpenGL 2.0.

Genymotion can be used with tools that connect to an existing display. Tools known to work this way include TightVNC on Windows, macOS screen sharing and x11vnc on Linux.

Genymotion cannot be used with tools that create a new display (unless this display supports OpenGL). For example, Genymotion cannot be used with RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) tools, X11-forwarding, or TightVNC Server on Linux.

Comment: It takes me two hour to turn it out

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the remote server any more. By the way, thanks for the time you have devoted to find a solution for this problem and hope it help others who they are stick in same situation.